# How to create a app like google play instant games in iOS and android using flutter

Tags: flutter, google-play-games, facebook-instant-games

I need to create an app using Flutter that can play games without downloading the whole app to mobile in Android and ios, I found Google Play instant games app in android but I do not have any idea how it works, also i need that app in ios,i did not find any app like that, can someone help about this, any help is much appreciated